# Argument of type 'Location' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | URL'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm using Vue with TypeScript and would like to call the app with the url

> http://localhost:5173?foo=bar

so I don't need a route hash. Given the following code:

```
const getUrlParameter = (name: string) => {
  const url = new URL(window.location);

  const parameter = url.searchParams.get(name);

  // ...
};
```

It returns `bar` when passing in `'foo'` so it seems it's working as expected. But TS comes up with the error message

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Location' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | URL'.   Type 'Location' is missing the following properties from type 'URL': password, searchParams, username, toJSON

Should I suppress this message? Are there ways to fix it?

Comment: may be this ? 
 const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const parameter = queryParams.get(name);

Comment: Yes, `const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);` is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

may be this ?

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); 
const parameter = queryParams.get(name);
```